# Hermite polynomials and the quantum harmonic oscilator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I know that the Hermite differential equation is:

$$y'' − 2x y' + 2ny = 0$$

and the solutions of this differential equations are $H_n(x)$.

However, the quantum harmonic oscillator is of the form:

$$-a y'' +(x^2-\lambda)y = 0$$

I cannot see why the solutions of this differential equation involve hermite polynomials? Is there a way to convert the second ode to the first ode?

Comment: you need to get rid of the gaussian prefactor for the qho.

Comment: And you figure out the correct Gaussian prefactor by considering the asymptotic behavior of the wavefunction at large $|x|$.

Comment: You're not making your life easier by using the same symbol $y$ in both equations as they are for *different* things.  It's a bad habit to get into and leads to mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A serious stylistic glitch in your two equivalent ODEs is to use the same dependent variable for both, when, clearly, they are not the same. Also, having nondimensionalized, as probably described in your text, *a*=1. So, since
$$-  y'' +(x^2-\lambda)y = 0$$
has messy scaling properties, you enhance, as always, its homogeneity by
redefining
$$
y\equiv e^{-x^2/2} u(x)
$$
so that
$$
y'= e^{-x^2/2} (u' -xu), \implies \\
y''= e^{-x^2/2} (u'' -2xu'+ x^2 u -u),
$$
so your original ODE reduces to just
$$u'' − 2x u' + (\lambda -1)u = 0,$$
which you appear to know has the Hermite polynomials as solutions for $\lambda -1=2n$, as your text probably reminds you of...

To sum up, eigenfunctions for the oscillator are *not* Hermite polynomials, but gaussian-enveloped such, namely [***Hermite functions***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions), [eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform).

Comment: Interesting! In a different context they would be called Hermite-Gauss modes.

Comment: I always thought that Hermite polynomials were about [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline).

Comment: @flippiefanus , Indeed, they are also called [Hermite-Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions).